# how to append information from a return $.getJSON value?

Tags: jquery, json

how to append information from a return $.getJSON value?

Here is the return data from $.getJSON

Test

I need to add additional information to this inner element once returned from the $.getJSON call with the variable testNumber.

```
        <p> Test  + testNumber + </p>
```

Here is my attempt but not working the right way....

```
        $.getJSON("getTestInformation.php", function(function(data)
        {
                    $.each(data, function()
                    {
                           $(".addTest").html(value).append(testNumber);
                    });
        });
```

The output I'm getting is this:

```
       <p> Test </p> 1
```

What I need is this?

```
       <p> Test  1 </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  $('<p>').html(value + ' ' + testNumber).appendTo('.addTest');
});
```

Comment: still working the same as before when viewing it from firebug, not working correctly

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene Could you make a demo? that will be quick to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$.getJSON("getTestInformation.php", function(function(data)
    {
                $.each(data, function()
                {
                       var txt = $(".addTest").text();
                       $(".addTest").text(text + ' ' + testNumber);
                });
    });
```

or

```
$.getJSON("getTestInformation.php", function(function(data)
    {
                $.each(data, function()
                {
                       $(".addTest").html(value + $("<span>").text(testNumber));
                });
    });
```